# how to include php in javascript for retriving data from database to form a paper with MCQ questions

Tags: javascript, php

```
       <?php

            $server = "localhost";
            $username = "";
            $password = "";
            $db = "test";
            $conn = new mysqli($server,$username,$password,$db);

            if($conn->error){
                die("Error :- ". $conn->error);
            }

            $query = "select * from mcq_questions";
            $result = $conn->query($query);
      ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var n = <?php echo $result->num_rows ?>;
        var i;

            for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
                var question = "";
                question = '<?php  
                            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                            echo $row['question'];
                    ?>';
                document.write(question);
            }
     </script>
```

i wanted to print all the MCQ questions present in the database along with multiple options, but the problem when i am doing this only the first question is being printed n number of time.... can some one help me with this.

Comment: Try printing entire javascript code using php.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate inside PHP and print out the string as JS array to your `question` variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var n = <?php echo $result->num_rows ?>;
    var i;

        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
            var question = "";
            question = '<?php  
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo $row['question'] . ','
                }
              ?>';
            document.write(question);
        }
 </script>
```

look at this explanation: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: if we do as you said it will just print the all the questions separated by coma that to n number of times, What i wanted is one question is to printed and some options for it and then other question and its options and so no...

Comment: so just add option output like  $row['question'] . ', ' . $row['options_column_name'] . ', '

Comment: @AndiryKuba    actually what i wanted is first initially one question should be printed and upon clicking next button the other question should be printed and so on till the last question. At a time only one question should be visible on the screen.